# Incompatible version of react-devtools-core in react-native-debugger@0.13.0

Tags: react-native, react-devtools, react-native-debugger

I upgraded `react-native-debugger` from 0.11.6 to 0.13.0, and when I try to run my app, the debugger logs the error `Unsupported Bridge operation "0" An incompatible version of react-devtools-core has been embedded in a renderer like React Native. To fix this, update the react-devtools-core package within the React Native application, or downgrade the react-devtools package you use to open the DevTools UI.`

In the documentation for 0.13.0, it says to add the following to my `package.json`:

```
{
  "overrides": {
     "react-devtools-core": "~4.25.0"
  }
}
```

I checked that this 4.25.0 is the most recent version of react-devtools-core, so I can't do what the error says and upgrade it. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

It should say in the Flipper error which devtools version it uses. For example here it uses `4.27.2`.

Then check your `node_modules` folder for `react-devtools-core` in the package.json file to see which version your react-native has installed.

You can then check the different branches in the official react-native repo to see the [package files](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.67-stable/package.json) and which devtools versions it requires.

You will need to either downgrade your Flipper (you can also check its dependencies in the official repo) or upgrade your React Native version so that they are compatible.

You can download [old versions of Flipper here](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/releases).

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1255289)